# How would I take a row-wise average values for certain columns, while retaining other in my dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to figure out how to take the averages of multiple rows (for a subset of columns), grouped by a user ID, while retaining other columns.

For example I have df:

```
df
| user_id |    date    | value1 | value2 | value3 | zipcode |
|---------|------------|--------|--------|--------|---------|
|  13579  | 2020-05-01 |   100  |  134   |   826  |  85001  |
|  13579  | 2020-05-02 |   234  |  153   |   725  |  85001  |
|  13579  | 2020-05-03 |   241  |  186   |   926  |  85001  |
|  24681  | 2020-05-01 |   246  |  135   |   257  |  60629  |
|  24681  | 2020-05-02 |   200  |  252   |   264  |  60629  |
|  24681  | 2020-05-03 |   210  |  134   |   302  |  60629  |
```

Ideally I would want the output to look like:

```
df_avg
| user_id | value1 | value2 | value3 | zipcode |
|---------|--------|--------|--------|---------|
|  13579  |  191.7 |  157.7 |  825.6 |  85001  |
|  24681  |  218.7 |  173.7 |  274.3 |  60629  |
```

As you can see, the columns value1, value2, and value3 would be averaged as new rows (or would these be considered series now that they're a new df?), grouped by user_id, and still have classifier variables like zipcode.

Originally, I thought something like `df_avg = df.loc[:, 'value1':'value3'].groupby('user_id').mean()` would work, but after running it and getting a KeyError, its obvious that my code doesn't include the user_id to actually group by.

I'm still relatively new to Pandas, and python as a whole and I'm a bit stuck from here. Would a lambda function be best for this kind of task?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Looking more so how to do this conceptually, not necessarily how to perform the operation on this DF specifically - this is just dummy data. I will be scaling this up to a much larger dataframe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do it with `grouby.agg` and use `first` on the column zipcode

```
print (df.groupby('user_id').agg(value1=('value1', 'mean'), 
                                 value2=('value2', 'mean'), 
                                 value3=('value3', 'mean'), 
                                 zipcode=('zipcode', 'first'))
         .reset_index())
   user_id      value1      value2      value3  zipcode
0    13579  191.666667  157.666667  825.666667    85001
1    24681  218.666667  173.666667  274.333333    60629
```

Comment: @Ch3steR actually your answer made me realized that using mean on zipcode would give the same result here (I did not pay attention to it before) so I'm not sure that first was what the OP wanted now...

Comment: Both would work I think - but just to further my own knowledge, is there a way to make it scale a little better? For example, I sometimes work with daily data split into 15 minute intervals, which gives me 96 rows to average. I know there would have to be a better way than hardcoding all of those columns. Would something like .loc or .iloc be applicable there? Or perhaps unpivoting and dealing with it row-wise, similar to the code above?

Comment: @Mac I'm not sure to follow the link between the 96 rows to average and hardcoding all of those columns? does it mean that your columns are the intervals?but then what do you aggregate? note that if you perform the same operation to all of them, then the answer of YOBEN_S is easier to use

Comment: @Mac or like @Ch3steR posted but deleted `df.groupby('user_id').agg('mean')`

Comment: @Ben.T Gotcha. Sorry for not being clear - you assumed correctly, the 96 intervals are all separate columns that need to be averaged. I guess my fear was if I had other necessary columns that could get caught up in the calculation. But that answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: @Mac if you have a list of columns' name to aggregate like `l_cols=['value1','value2']`, you can also select these columns between groupby and agg like `df.groupby('user_id')[l_cols].agg('mean')`

Answer (score 3):

We can just do

```
df=df.drop('date',axis=1).groupby('user_id').mean()
```